# Load balancer based on percentage distribution algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, rest, load-balancing

Let's assume I have the following entities:

```
public class Account {
    private String id;
    private List<Host> hosts;
}

public class Host {
    private String name;
    private int percentageLoad;
}
```

I have a web application with only one endpoint `/check` with an `accountId` as a request parameter.

An example of a request could be: `localhost:8080/check?accountId=123456`.

That service has to validate that `accountId` exists in an embedded database, and if so, it answers with a host's name. Those hosts have a load percentage and the answers should be balanced depending on their load percentage.

It may be confusing what I want to explain, so I will put an example:

Assume that I have in the database the following `Account`:

```
Account:
  - id: 123
  - hosts: [{machine1, 60}, {machine2, 40}]
```

As you can see that the account has `123` as id and two hosts with one percentage load for each one.

If I get the following request: `localhost:8080/check?accountId=123`, then as that account id exists in the database, it should balance the host's name answer depending on the percentage load.

More clear, let's say I make 10 similar requests: `localhost:8080/check?accountId=123`, then the hostname `machine1` should be returned 6 times (as it has a load percentage of 60%), and `machine2` should be returned 4 times (as it has a load percentage of 40%).

I really don't know which strategy to apply in order to balance it.

I thought about a counter which counts the number of answers for each machine. Or pick a random number between 0 and 10 and decide one machine or another depending on that number. But I think they are not good approaches, any idea about an algorithm to balance that?

Comment: Go for random. If you have so much traffic that you need to think about load balancing, the pseudo-random approach should be just fine. Compared to counting (in a limited time window), there is no need to keep state.

Comment: Random will not guarantee the correct balance, if I'm unlucky the `machine1` could be returned in every request :S

Answer (score 3):

You'll need another variable in the `Host` class:

```
public class Host {
    private String name;
    private int percentageLoad;
    private int percentageAccum;
}
```

The initial value for `percentageAccum` is the value of `percentageLoad`.

When a request is received:

- choose the host with the largest `percentageAccum`
- subtract 100 from the `percentageAccum` for the chosen host
- add `percentageLoad` to `percentageAccum` for all hosts, including the chosen host

A slight optimization is to determine the next choice while updating the `percentageAccum` for all of the hosts.

Comment: Wonderful! Behaves just as expected.

Comment: What is the intuition for that algorithm though

Comment: @AmrSaber To gain intuition about the algorithm, run the algorithm with a simple example (like the one in the question). At each step, print the variables for each `Host` class, and the **sum** of the `percentageAccum` variables.

Comment: @user3386109  hello, i implemented this algo in java and ran for 10 sample calls. There is a deviation in percentage routing for my output. Can you please have a look on [this result on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/nuqV2rNX) and tell me if you find something odd, not sure where i am going wrong in java!? –

Comment: @NoobEditor If you post the code ([mcve]) in a question here on SO, I'll take a look.

Comment: @user3386109 [here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67226958/percentage-based-routing-algorithm), please help!