# Percentage based routing algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, routes

browsing around for *percentage based routing*, stumbled upon [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52044571/3154233).

per the algo proposed as below:

for a given model as below:

```
public class Host {
    private String name;
    private int percentageLoad;
    private int percentageAccum;
}
```

The initial value for percentageAccum is the value of percentageLoad.

When a request is received:

- choose the host with the largest percentageAccum
- subtract 100 from the percentageAccum for the chosen host
- add percentageLoad to percentageAccum for all hosts, including the chosen host

below is my implementation

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HostWeightage{
    private String hostId;
    private int weightage;
    private int accumulatedWeightageSoFar;
}
```

---

Sample Java executor

```
public String getRoutedHost(List<HostWeightage> hostWeightageList) {
    
    // assume 0th index as default 
    HostWeightage hostWithMaxAccWeight = hostWeightageList.get(0);
 
    // choose the host with the largest percentageAccum
    for (int i = 1; i < hostWeightageList.size(); i++) {
        if (hostWeightageList.get(i).getAccumulatedWeightageSoFar() >= hostWithMaxAccWeight.getAccumulatedWeightageSoFar()){
            hostWithMaxAccWeight = hostWeightageList.get(i);
        }
    }
 
    // subtract 100 from the percentageAccum for the chosen host
    int inverseAccWeight = hostWithMaxAccWeight.getAccumulatedWeightageSoFar() - 100;
    hostWithMaxAccWeight.setAccumulatedWeightageSoFar(inverseAccWeight);
    
 
    // add percentageLoad to percentageAccum for all hosts, including the chosen host
    int weight = hostWithMaxAccWeight.getWeightage();
    for (HostWeightage wightedHost : hostWeightageList) {
        int accWeight = wightedHost.getAccumulatedWeightageSoFar();
        wightedHost.setAccumulatedWeightageSoFar(weight + accWeight);
    }
 
    return hostWithMaxAccWeight.getHostId();
}
```

---

here is my sample runs for 10 calls each

```
INFO: initial config
HostWeightage(hostId=redirect_host_1, weightage=10, accumulatedWeightageSoFar=10), 
HostWeightage(hostId=redirect_host_2, weightage=40, accumulatedWeightageSoFar=40), 
HostWeightage(hostId=redirect_host_3, weightage=50, accumulatedWeightageSoFar=50)
final distribution of 10 calls:
INFO: host1 3 ( should have been 1)
INFO: host2 3 ( should have been 4)
INFO: host3 4 ( should have been 5)
-------------------------
INFO: initial config 
HostWeightage(hostId=redirect_host_1, weightage=30, accumulatedWeightageSoFar=30), 
HostWeightage(hostId=redirect_host_2, weightage=30, accumulatedWeightageSoFar=30), 
HostWeightage(hostId=redirect_host_3, weightage=40, accumulatedWeightageSoFar=40)
final distribution of 10 calls:
INFO: host1 3 ( correct output )
INFO: host2 3 ( correct output )
INFO: host3 4 ( correct output )
-------------------------
INFO: initial config 
HostWeightage(hostId=redirect_host_1, weightage=10, accumulatedWeightageSoFar=10), 
HostWeightage(hostId=redirect_host_2, weightage=20, accumulatedWeightageSoFar=20), 
HostWeightage(hostId=redirect_host_3, weightage=70, accumulatedWeightageSoFar=70)
final distribution of 10 calls:
INFO: host1 3 ( should have been 1 )
INFO: host2 3 ( should have been 2 )
INFO: host3 4 ( should have been 7 )
```

any pointers to what is wrong in algo implementation is appreciated!!

Comment: Why does your routing have to be deterministic?

Comment: @ernest_k hello, use case for which this is being implemented, it needs _predictability_, something like what payment gateways do. little bit buffer in deviation is acceptable but if you look at first sample, _1st host_ was supposed to get least traffic but it ended up getting same as _2nd host_, this would fail the purpose!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing a point here, but I guess most algorithms like this work at honoring your weightings *eventually*, i.e., the higher the number of calls, the more precisely the weightings are reflected... a bit like how probability proves itself with larger samples.

Comment: @ernest_k aligned with your thot process but i have seen these algos working with _precision_ for small data sets as well. so there must be some _magic sauce_??

Comment: Right, I'm not trying to say that it can't be done, it definitely can. I'm just questioning the need for it as I can't see such requirement being justified for real-world load-balancing. But my perspective could simply be very limited.

Comment: @ernest_k i can think of 2 distinct example, _server load balancers_ serve with the logic you mentioned ( _non deterministic_) , services like _call centers / payment gateways_ ( _deterministic_ ) where precision is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the loop at the end of the code. It's using the same weight for all of the hosts, due to the line:

```
int weight = hostWithMaxAccWeight.getWeightage();
```

The weight that's added to each host's accumulator needs to be that host's weight, not the weight of the host that was chosen. So the loop should be:

```
for (HostWeightage weightedHost : hostWeightageList) {
    int weight = weightedHost.getWeightage();
    int accWeight = weightedHost.getAccumulatedWeightageSoFar();
    weightedHost.setAccumulatedWeightageSoFar(weight + accWeight);
}
```

A sample run of the algorithm using weights `A:10 B:80 C:10` looks like this:

```
accumulators
  A   B   C
 10  80  10  choose B  
 20  60  20  choose B  
 30  40  30  choose B 
 40  20  40  choose  A  
-50 100  50  choose B  
-40  80  60  choose B  
-30  60  70  choose  C  
-20 140 -20  choose B  
-10 120 -10  choose B  
  0 100   0  choose B  
 10  80  10  back to start
```

Comment: {A: 10; B:80;C:10} -> result(A: 0 calls, B: 9 calls, C: 1 calls) **||** {A: 20; B:50;C:30} -> result(A: 2 calls, B: 4 calls, C: 4 calls). seems still deviation, is this an _eventual consistent algo_ ?

Comment: @NoobEditor No, this is a dead on, first time, every time algo.

Comment: @NoobEditor The accum values should be 
 `{10,80,10 - B}`
 `{20,60,20 - B}`
 `{30,40,30 - B}`
 `{40,20,40 - A}`
 `{-50,100,50 - B}`
 `{-40,80,60 - B}`
 `{-30,60,70 - C}`
 `{-20,140,-20 - B}`
 `{-10,120,-10 - B}`
 `{0,100,0 - B}`
 `{10,80,10 - back to start}` so that's 1A 8B and 1C, exactly as requested.

Comment: thank you, this helps. my accumulated weight is wrong. debugging it to fix.